# Upate a java file in war file

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am working on a project and the project is in running state. As there is some issue in a java file and I have resolved that issue. But I don't have an idea how to update that particular java file in war file which is deployed on the company server.Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat doesn't support hot deployment. SO you have to restart Tomcat anyhow.
And if you are going to restart it, either replace the .class file(the one which u have changed) or generate new war and then retart Tomcat. Your changes will be reflected.

Update : for hot deployment http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-deploy-procedures

Comment: Last hotdeployment method, not discussed in an article, is a manual commandline copy-rename-overwrite war deployment. This is fine especially in a development environment. I've used it in production as well, ANT script doing scp copy over network. Our Tomcat don't have /manager webapps for security reasons. Just yesterday gave this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094477/how-to-upload-a-war-file-on-tomcat-7-cookbook-by-chef/21095126#21095126

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your new java .class file into your extracted project folder under tomcat

Comment: No, this wont work if the class is already loaded, which must be the case here

Answer (score 0):

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Reload_An_Existing_Application

This will cause a service interruption anyway, but probably still shorter than restarting the whole server.

Note that this will only works when the web application is deployed from an unpacked directory, otherwise you will have to undeploy and deploy again the web app.

(http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Undeploy_an_Existing_Application)